# Using typed.js with React function components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, typed.js

[typed.js](https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js) doesn't offer an example for this in the docs, only for [class components](https://jsfiddle.net/mattboldt/ovat9jmp/):

```js
class TypedReactDemo extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const options = { ... };
    this.typed = new Typed(this.el, options );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <span ref={(el) => { this.el = el; }} />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import Typed from "typed.js";

const Example = () => {
  const typeTarget = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const typed = new Typed(typeTarget.current, {
      strings: ["<i>First</i> sentence.", "&amp; a second sentence."],
      typeSpeed: 40,
    });

    return () => {
      typed.destroy();
    };
  }, []);

  return <span ref={typeTarget} />;
};

export default Example;
```