# Trying to use Typed.js in react

Tags: html, reactjs, typed.js

I am trying to use Typed.js on my website, and I have been getting many errors I cant find a way to fix them.

I have looked through GitHub, and I have found the exact same problem that someone had I used that code in my document and the errors are still popping up. The errors are always `Expression Expected` and `} expected` also, `Unexpected token. Did you mean {'}?`  Here is a picture of the errors too. ***Here is the errors that are resulting:***
[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqHGh.jpg)

```js
import "./App.css";
import Typed from "typed.js";
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

function HomePage() {
  return (
    <>
      <body>
        <div class="hero">
          <nav>
            <h2 class="logo">JAKEISTHATMAN.</h2>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">About</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Services</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="./contact.js">Portfolio</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <button type="button">Contact</button>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="container"></div>

        <div class="main-text">
          <h1>
            I'm a <span class="type"></span>
          </h1>
          <p>
            Also I work for <b>@no</b> media team!
          </p>
          <button type="button">Contact</button>
        </div>

        export default function Typed() {
    const TypedElement = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!TypedElement.current) return;

        const typed = new Typed(TypedElement.current, {
            strings: [
                "string",
                "string2",
                "string3",
            ],
            startDelay: 300,
            typeSpeed: 100,
            backSpeed: 100,
            backDelay: 500,
            loop: true,
        });

        // Destroying
        return () => {
            typed.destroy();
        };
    }, []);
  
   return <span ref={TypedElement}></span>
}

      </body>
    </>
  );
}

export default HomePage;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using typed.js with React function components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63713978/using-typed-js-with-react-function-components)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if the code example above is how your code really is, it won't work because you just have javascript in an html tag all of a sudden. Try wrapping the javascript with curly brackets to let the file know you are typing javascript code now like this:

```js
<div>
  {console.log("this is javascript")}
</div>
```

Second, it looks like you are trying to define a functional component called `Typed`. At the very least, it is poor organization to define a functional component inside an html tag like you have done above (if it isn't impossible, not sure, never tried it). You should define the functional component called `Typed` outside the `HomePage` function, like so:

```
import "./App.css";
import Typed from "typed.js";
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const Example = ({args_if_necessary}) => {
  const typeTarget = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const typed = new Typed(typeTarget.current, {
      strings: ["<i>First</i> sentence.", `use ${args_if_necessary}`],
      typeSpeed: 40,
    });

    return () => {
      typed.destroy();
    };
  }, []);

  return <span ref={typeTarget} />;
};

function HomePage() {
    
  return (
    <>
      <body>
        <your-other-html />

        <Example args_if_necessary={"something"} />

      </body>
    </>
  );
}

export default HomePage;
```

Comment: I am having trouble. I am getting the error in the console: Identifier Typed has already been declared. and also, DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/typed.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

Comment: that's my bad, see edit